# How to define closing behaviour of an instance of a Window in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have found that one can add Closing property inside Window tag in .xaml file and then define closing behaviour in the c# file.

```
<Window 
  ...
  Closing="DataWindow_Closing">
```

Which works fine.

In my case I have an instance of a window that is defined in c# like this:

```
    public bool ShowDial()
    {
      var window = new Window
      {
        Content = this,
        ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
      };
      ...
    }
```

How to define closing behaviour of this window that is instantiated in c# and not in xaml file?

P.S.
I have a UserControl defined in .xaml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Closing` is an event: see [Window.Closing Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.closing).

Attach en event handler

```cs
window.Closing += DataWindow_Closing;
```

And declare the handler as

```cs
void DataWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //TODO: add your code here
}
```

---

When you type `window.Closing+=` in Visual Studio, a tool tip pops up inviting you to press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]

If you do so, the event handler will be created automatically for you like this:

```cs
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

In this handler you can set `e.Cancel = true;` if you don't want the window to be closed, e.g. when a validation failed and the data could not be saved.

Answer (score 2):

`Closing` is an event. You need to give it a listener.
An example with using a lambda expression.

```cs
    public bool ShowDial()
    {
      var window = new Window
      {
        Content = this,
        ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
      };
      window.Closing += (s, e) =>
      {
          // Some Code
      };
      ...
    }
```